# Validate Two Inputs which depends on each other

Tags: laravel-5

I have two Inputs 'creditor' and 'debtor' , I want The user to put value in one of them at least, or both.
this is the approach  i am using

```
if($request->input('creditor')==Null && $request->input('debtor')==Null){
        Session::flash('danger','Please add Value in one of the two inputs at least');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

How to do the same thing with laravel validation
like in example :

```
 $request->validate([
        'creditor' => 'required',
        'debtor' => 'required',

    ]
```

but what i want if one of the inputs has  avalue there is no need to check for the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle this problem but I recommend you use `$request->filled()` as it checks if a field is present and that it has value. So, it does `isset()` and `!empty()` together.

The `||` AKA `OR` logic returns `true` if one of the statements/conditions is true and returns false if both conditions are false.

```
if($request->filled('creditor') || $request->filled('debtor')){
    // Either of the has value in it.
} else {
    Session::flash('danger','Please add Value in one of the two inputs at least');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**EDIT**

Your could also use [required_without_all:foo,bar,](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all)

**An Example:**

```
$rules = array(
    'creditor' => 'required_without_all:debtor',
    'debtor' => 'required_without_all:creditor',
);

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

if($validator->fails()){
    Session::flash('danger','Please add Value in one of the two inputs at least');
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: i am looking for way to user laravel validator like    $request->validate([  ]),

Comment: You cannot upvote yet but you can accept an answer. Take a look at this...https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check with OR operator..